# Install GDAL extension on GeoServer 2.9-SNAPSHOT

Tags: geoserver, gdal

I have GeoServer on Ubuntu 14 as part of a Geonode 2.6 install.  I am having trouble installing the GDAL extensions.  The version of GeoServer says 2.9-SNAPSHOT.

I have tried to install the GDAL extensions following the instructions here - http://docs.geoserver.org/2.9.3/user/data/raster/gdal.html

I used the GeoServer 2.9.4 GDAL extensions. After restarting GeoServer, the additional coverage formats aren't available.

gdalinfo --version returns the correct version, and
gdalinfo --formats returns the list of supported formats.

I can't find anything obvious in the log file, there is a reference to - 
 *ArcSDE Java API seems to not be on your classpath. Please verify that all needed jars are. ArcSDE data stores will not be available.*

and then

*2017-06-27 03:31:35,393 DEBUG [gdal.envihdr] - EnviHdrFormatFactory is not availaible.
2017-06-27 03:31:35,393 DEBUG [gdal.jp2mrisd] - JP2MrSIDFormatFactory is not availaible.
2017-06-27 03:31:35,393 DEBUG [gdal.jp2ecw] - JP2ECWFormatFactory is not availaible.
2017-06-27 03:31:35,393 DEBUG [gdal.mrsid] - MrSIDFormatFactory is not availaible.  ...........etc*

I have updated the \etc\environment file to include the path, still nothing.

Comment: Versions have to match. So you need extensions from a 2.9-SNAPSHOT (ideally the same 2.9-SNAPSHOT). 2.9.4 is not close enough.

Comment: and it should be the snapshot from the day you downloaded the server war

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can download [gdal-plugin](http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.9.x/ext-2017-11-18/geoserver-2.9-SNAPSHOT-gdal-plugin.zip) from [bondlessgeo](http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.9.x/ext-2017-11-18/) site. Also you can learn how to install it form [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html)

Have a nice day.